# Divs Appear Anytime User Scrolls - Not When In View

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

So, I am working on my portfolio website, and I have been having some issues with my bar graph. I am trying to set it for it to appear when it comes into view on scroll. So far, I have been able to achieve the effect to work correctly, but it does so as soon as the user scrolls - not when it comes into view. What am I doing incorrectly? Also, I should note I am using a plugin for my website, called LiveQuery.

HTML:

```
<div id="section-three">
        <div id="web-head">
            <h2>Web Development</h2>
            <br>
            <p><i>Code, code, and more code!</i></p>
        </div>
        <div id="web-graph">
            <div id="html-bar">
                <p>HTML</p>
                <div id="html">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="css-bar">
                <p>CSS</p>
                <div id="css">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="jq-bar">
                <p>JQuery/JavaScript</p>
                <div id="jq">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    /*SECTION THREE CODE*/

#section-three {
    min-width: 100vw;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

#web-head {
    max-width: 70vw;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: white;
}

#web-head h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

#web-head p {
    color: #808080;
}

#web-graph {
    min-width: 85vw;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
}

#web-graph p {
    float: left;
    max-width: 14vw;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 37.5px;
    color: white;
}

#html-bar {
    flex: 1;
}

#html {
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 70vw;
    width: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#html.active {
    background-color: #808080;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 70vw;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#css-bar {
    flex: 1;
}

#css {
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 70vw;
    width: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#css.active {
    background-color: #808080;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 65vw;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#jq-bar {
    flex: 1;
}

#jq {
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 70vw;
    width: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#jq.active {
    background-color: #808080;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    min-height: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 35vw;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jq-bar:visible').livequery(function () {
        $('#html').addClass('active');
        $('#css').addClass('active');
        $('#jq').addClass('active');
    })             
});
```

I should also note that I had previously tried linking it to whenever a div or an item with a certain ID or class showed, it will trigger the function, but it still didn't work, unfortunately. If someone would be able to point me in the correct direction, I would highly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your selector immediately selects the elements on page load:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jq-bar:visible')
```

Shamelessly stolen from [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_visible.asp):

> Definition and Usage The :visible selector selects every element that
>   is currently visible.
>
> Visible elements are elements that are not:
>   Set to display:none
>   Form elements with type="hidden"
>   Width and height set to 0
>   A hidden parent element (this also hides child elements)

If you're trying to track when something is visible you could try to use something like scroll top to initialize the classes.